# Will my Rails model and controller names collide with Rails' reserved words?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm about to create a new Rails 6 application with the model / table names `Requests` and `Routes` and the controller names `RequestsController` and `RoutesController`.

Will these work in a Rails 6 application?

When I run `rails generate model Request` everything looks normal. Rails doesn't complain.

But according to [this list](https://www.wikitechy.com/tutorials/ruby-on-rails/reserved-word-list-in-ruby-on-rails) `Request` is a reserved word in Rails.

So will this work or will this get me into trouble? I would like to know before because renaming models in Rails can be cumbersome.

Comment: Cheap enough to create a new application and try it -- but as Rails is very convention driven you will likely be fighting the framework to make it understood what class you are referring to at any given time. Best to give them unique names and use the translation tools to show friendly names to the users.

Comment: It definitely is asking for a kick in the genitals as masking `@request` in your controller will mess things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I did **not** run into any problems with my approach. I was able to name my models `Request` and `Route` and didn't get any errors so far. I also have a `RequestsController` and a `RoutesController`.

Answer (score 0):

You will run into problems. Eg if you create a table named length it will cause problems so it's almost certain words on the reserved list will also.

Not a lot to gain with a lot to lose. Sometimes they will only cause issues when trying to scale an application eg have more than once instance of an app running.

Comment: I think I proved you wrong. But thanks for the input anyway.

Comment: Key phrase "so far". No one suggested you wouldn't be able to create the tables only that it will likely cause problems. I gave an example how some problems only show up when running more than one instance of an app.